# How to Read Deployment Events from New Relic api?

Tags: deployment, newrelic

How can I read Deployment Events that I have recorded in New Relic.

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/new-relic-apm/maintenance/setting-deployment-notifications#more_help
Documents shows how to record deployment events. But nothing about how to read them back.

I know I can see them on deployment dashboard.
https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/applications-menu/events/deployments-dashboard

**Anyone know how to read them through API?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently New Relic doesn't have any api to read deployment events

Answer (score 0):

You can see the deployments you've sent up to New Relic on your Deployments Dashboard:

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/applications-menu/events/deployments-dashboard